# How can i delete an element of array in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have for example this array and i want to know how can i delete for example 65.

```
notas db 25,65,90,50,75,35,80
```

Thanks,

Comment: You have to copy all the later elements 1 byte earlier to close the "hole"

Comment: And adjust your notion of the length of the array (or else fill the last slot with 0?).